# Lexical rank of user entered string at the time it got entered

Tags: java, string, lexical

User have to input number of strings he will enter**(N)** and then value of those strings,
We have to tell lexical rank of string at the time it got entered

**Input- 5, (yyy,mmm,aaa,bbb,zzz)
**Output-1,1,1,2,5

procedure- 
step 1- as "yyy" is only string so only lexical rank given to it is 1
        OUTPUT-1

step 2- as we have 2 strings(yyy,mmm) but lexically mmm is first among given strings 
         so output 1

step 3- we have 3 strings(yyy,mmm,aaa) now but aaa is lexically first among 
        given strings so output is 1

step- 4 we have 4 strings(yyy,mmm,aaa,bbb) now but bbb is lexically second (aaa is first)among given strings so output is 2

step 5 we have 5 strings now(yyy,mmm,aaa,bbb,zzz) but zzz is lexically fifth among given strings so output is 5

Comment: and where is your Java code so far? Nobody here will write you the whole code. So where is the problem? Java provides a bunch of String operations, like split, substring, pattern matching via regex, etc. - it also has datastructures like lists and utils like Collections.sort. The rest is trivial, isn't it? At each step, put the new value `val` to the list, sort the list, and then ask for the index of `val` in the list. done

Comment: obviously i haven't asked for whole code anyone can write how to take string input and how to sort but problem is how to sort dynamically because we have to enter lexical rank at the time that string got entered

even if i write how i took input and how i sorted string array after all five values are entered
thats meaningless here

its hardly takes 5 lines of code or 2-3 lines of english text to explain how we can dynamically find lexical rank of string
so whole code not required either

Comment: @UmeshPathak Did you try out any logic & implementation so far? If yes, please do post the same in your question!

Comment: @UmeshPathak and I told you how to do it. Use a list, in each step put the element into the list, sort the list, then get the index from the list - that's it, done

Comment: String[] str={"yyy","mmm","aaa","bbb","zzz"};
        int n=5;
        ArrayList<String> arr=new ArrayList<String>();
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            arr.add(str[i]);
            Collections.sort(arr); 
            System.out.println(arr.indexOf(str[i])+1);
        }

Comment: very good, and now post it as an **answer** here if it works as expected

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] str={"yyy","mmm","aaa","bbb","zzz"};
int n=5;
ArrayList<String> arr=new ArrayList<String>();
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            arr.add(str[i]);
            Collections.sort(arr);
            System.out.println(arr.indexOf(str[i])+1);
        }
```